# How to inverse the result of this pyramid in python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

We have an exercise for our programming class and we have to inverse the result of this code.

basis:

```
line = 8
while line >= 1:
    number = 1
    while number <= line:
        print(number, end = '')
        number = number + 1
    line = line - 1
    print('')
```

output:

```
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

I've been struggling to get it to look like this:

```
87654321
7654321
654321
54321
4321
321
21
1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just invert your loop (nested while) invariant:

```
line = 8
while line >= 1:
    number = line
    while number > 0:
        print(number, end='')
        number = number - 1
    line = line - 1
    print('')
```

**Output:**

```
87654321
7654321
654321
54321
4321
321
21
1
```